# C++: No matching function call to base class function

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

```
 class Dobberman: public Dog
    {
    public:
        Dobberman()
            : Dog()
        {
            strncpy(_breed, "Dobberman", 20);
        }
        Dobberman( const char *name, const unsigned int age, const unsigned int pedigreeNo)
            : Dog(name,age), _pedigreeNo(pedigreeNo)
        {
        }
        ~Dobberman()
        {
        }
```

I get the above error when I try to compile. Honestly, no idea why.

Comment: If allowed within the confines of the assignment, I recommend replacing  the char arrays with std::strings. You will thank yourself later. If you can't use strings, replace all of the `20`s with a constant so you don't get nailed by missing one if you ever change the array size.

Comment: Please post the error. Not some link.

Comment: QUESTION ANSWERED. PLEASE NO FURTHER COMMENTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class Dog has a constructor with three parameters

```
 Dog(const char *name, const unsigned int age, char *breed)
```

but in the constructor of class `Dobberman` you call a Dog constructor with two arguments instead of three arguments

```
Dobberman( const char *name, const unsigned int age, const unsigned int pedigreeNo) 
    : Dog(name,age), _pedigreeNo(pedigreeNo) { } 
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So the compiler issues an error that it can not find a constructor in class `Dog` with two parameters.

Take into account that in any case this constructor

```
Dog(const char *name, const unsigned int age, char *breed)
{
    strncpy(_name, name, 20);
    _age = age;
    strncpy(_breed, breed, 20);
}
```

is defined incorrectly. For the third parameter you use string literals as the argument. So the third parameter has to be declared like `const char *breed`

In the body of the constructor instead of

```
    strncpy(_name, name, 20);
    strncpy(_breed, breed, 20);
```

you have to write

```
    strncpy(_name, name, 20);
    _name[19] = '\0';
    strncpy(_breed, breed, 20);
    _breed[19] = '\0';
```

Alsodestructor of class Dog should be declared as virtual. For example

```
virtual ~Dog() {}
```

or

```
virtual ~Dog() = default;
```